# How do you avoid "strategy.entry" prices from changing to the "open" price during back tests?

Tags: pine-script

Let's say I have a simple MACD strategy:

```
//@version=4
strategy("MACD Strategy", overlay=true)

fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)

MACD = ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ema(MACD, MACDLength)
delta = MACD - aMACD

if (crossover(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")

if (crossunder(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")

//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

And let's suppose I am using a 1-hour candle and that I get a signal to buy at a price of 100 when the time is, say 10:03 AM. Later when backtesting the strategy, the signal price changes to the open price of the candle, say 99, and the time of the signal changes to the start time of the candle, say 10:00 AM. So how do I avoid these changes and keep the price and time at the original position when the signal was generated?

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
strategy("MACD Strategy", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = true)

fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)

MACD = ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ema(MACD, MACDLength)
delta = MACD - aMACD

if (crossover(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")

if (crossunder(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")

plot(delta)
plot(0)
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I implement plot(delta) & plot(0) in the calculation of the profit percentage?

Comment: is this a question of another topic?

Comment: No it's the same question. How would plot(delta) & plot(0) help me in calculating the end result in terms of profit percentage?

Comment: I have no any idea about how would plot(delta) & plot(0) help you in calculating the end result in terms of profit percentage ) I've added it just for check/visualize that orders are executed in right bars